# Simplest way to display current month and year like "Aug 2016" in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, echo

What is the shortest, simplest code to generate the curent month in Full English like `September` or in abbreviated three letter version like `Feb` and then add the current Year `2011`?

So the code will, depending on the month and year, echo things like:

`August 2016` or  `Aug 2016` etcettera. Thanks!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Full version:

```
<? echo date('F Y'); ?>
```

Short version:

```
<? echo date('M Y'); ?>
```

Here is a [good reference for the different date options](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

**update**

To show the previous month we would have to introduce the [mktime()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function and make use of the optional `timestamp` parameter for the date() function. Like this:

```
echo date('F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1, 1, date('Y')));
```

This will also work (it's typically used to get the last day of the previous month):

```
echo date('F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 0, date('Y')));
```

Comment: @RDL +1 thanks! works beautifully. Now a small folowup question: what if you alwys want to show the previous month. something with -1 perhaps??  so it should show `Februari 2011` while its now March...

Comment: @RDL sure that helps alot thanks, hwoever dreamweaver complains about an error on this line `echo date('F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1, 1, date('Y'));` what do you recoon mate? thanks very much

Comment: @Sam, It was missing a closing bracket at the end.  Fixed it above.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Awesome! I deducted from your code that this would output only the previous month `date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1, 1))`  Thanks very much @RDL!

Answer (score 39):

Here is a simple and more update format of getting the data:

```
   $now = new \DateTime('now');
   $month = $now->format('m');
   $year = $now->format('Y');
```