# How get name of month in PHP?

Tags: php

I tried to get name of month in php:

```
$date = '2014-06-00';
echo $m = date('M', strtotime($date));
```

It gives me May month instead June.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there's a day 0 in June

Comment: check the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/5347225/1018966

Comment: I know. but question about how to get name of month froma date `'2014-06-00'` and I wrote my example.

Comment: @PiligrimBilim: Did you try using a valid date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $date = '2014-06-00';

    $monthNum  = substr($date, 5, 2);
    $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);

    echo  $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');

?>
```

Output:

```
June
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think simply to add + 1 for month

Comment: One question, hoe get short name? Found: `M`

Comment: @PiligrimBilim What do you mean with `short name` ?